# Visual Studio 2012 C++ console application exits Immediately

Tags: c++, opencv, console, exit

Im working with C++ In Visual Studio 2012 with the OpenCV library. 
The problem is that when I run my console application, after about 2 or 3 seconds it closes.
Heres the code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage *img)
{
    // Convert the image into an HSV image
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);

    cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

    IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);

    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgThreshed); //Detect Colour

    cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
    return imgThreshed;
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize capturing live feed from the camera
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); // cvCaptureFromCAM(0) indicates camera being used,           Change the 0 for a different camera

    // Couldn't get a device? Throw an error and quit
    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Camera not working\n");
        return -1;
    }

 // The two windows we'll be using
cvNamedWindow("video"); //Create new window containing video
cvNamedWindow("thresh"); //Create another window containing thresholded image

// This image holds the "scribble" data
// the tracked positions of the ball
IplImage* imgScribble = NULL;

// An infinite loop
while(true)
{
    // Will hold a frame captured from the camera
    IplImage* frame = 0;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    // If we couldn't grab a frame... quit
    if(!frame)
        printf("Couldnt get frame \n");



     // If this is the first frame, we need to initialize it
    if(imgScribble == NULL)
    {
        imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 3);
    }

    // Holds the yellow thresholded image (yellow = white, rest = black)
    IplImage* imgYellowThresh = GetThresholdedImage(frame);

    // Calculate the moments to estimate the position of the ball
    CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
    cvMoments(imgYellowThresh, moments, 1);

    // The actual moment values
    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

    // Holding the last and current ball positions
    static int posX = 0;
    static int posY = 0;

    int lastX = posX;
    int lastY = posY;

    posX = moment10/area;
    posY = moment01/area;

    // Print it out for debugging purposes
    printf("position (%d,%d)\n", posX, posY);

    // We want to draw a line only if its a valid position
    if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)
    {
        // Draw a yellow line from the previous point to the current point
        cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(0,255,255), 5);
    }

     // Add the scribbling image and the frame
    cvAdd(frame, imgScribble, frame);
    cvShowImage("thresh", imgYellowThresh);
    cvShowImage("video", frame);

    // Release the thresholded image+moments we need no memory leaks please
    cvReleaseImage(&imgYellowThresh);
    delete moments;

        // We're done using the camera. Other applications can now use it
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;

    // Wait for a keypress
    int c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if(c!=-1)
    {
        // If pressed, break out of the loop
        break;
    }

}
}
```

My Camera is working properly and it still quits.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Memory leaks, unchecked pointers ... what's not to love?

Comment: Rule of thumb: `Use pointers for pointer-arithmetic, references for everything else.`

Comment: You are using `malloc` to allocate memory and `delete` to free it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing together two ways of allocating/freeing memory - `malloc/free` and `new/delete` :

```
CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
```

and

```
delete moments;
```

You should not mix the two. `malloc/free` do not call constructor/destructor on the allocated memory. `new/delete` do call constructor/destructor on  the allocated memory, and MIGHT be using other memory function instead of `malloc/free` to allocate/free the actual memory. As a result, you can get all sorts of errors emanating from reasons ranging from calling a destructor on unconstructed object to using non-corresponding functions to allocate/free memory.

Plus, there can be other problems, of course. This is an obvious one and you should start by fixing it.

EDIT #1: While everything said above is true and should be fixed, [Andrey Smorodov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18043326/917249), probably, nailed it: you unconditionally `return` from inside the loop. I should've not stopped checking your code after I saw `malloc/delete` problem ;).

EDIT #2: To answer your comment. 
If `CvMoments` is a C-struct, use `free` instead of `delete`. If it is a C++ class, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

You also have to review the code in the end of your loop. It is hard to say what you want to do there. By the looks of it, I would put memory allocation for `moments` before the loop and free memory after the loop - you keep allocating/freeing same amount of memory. Do you even need it on heap? Can you not just put it on stack? It also seems that you want to keep working with camera until user pressed a key. Do you need to release camera AFTER user pressed a key or every time before you start waiting for it? In any case, your `return` statement exits the loop and `main` (and program) before control goes to `if` statement. Put `return` statement OUTSIDE the loop.

In short:

Before loop - allocate memory. Remember to use `malloc/free` or `new/delete`, but do not mix them. Think if you need heap at all, maybe stack is ok.

In loop - remove freeing memory, remove releasing camera, remove `return`. You will be using them on the next go through the loop, right? If user presses a key (inside the loop), you'll go out of the loop.

After the loop - now you really want to clean up. Free memory, release camera, `return` from `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @MatthewC I added an edit to the post. It's hard to say what you need exactly, but take a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc and delete cannot be used together, use free(ptr) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
// We're done using the camera. Other applications can now use it
```

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

return 0;

must be out of while loop body.